# Find specific text, in line above this text insert characters at set positions

Tags: python, ruby

I'm working with notepadd++ files, I have approx 70 files, and in each one, I need to add '20' in 2 locations on a line, around 15 times.

So in each ++ file I have:

> *CSTART
>
> UNKNOWN               -1.00
>    -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
>    -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
>
> 1811020926  1811110548   2
>
> ***CEND**

This set of lines, occurs several times, up to 15 throughout each file. I want to find each instance of **CEND**, and in the line above it, insert the number 20 before each date.

The line containing "1811020926  1811110548   2" is yy-mm-dd-hh-mm format, and I need it to be yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm format due to a bug in the software we use.

So we'd go from: 1811020926  1811110548   2

And end up with: 201811020926  201811110548   2

Anyone shed any light on how to do this in Ruby? I'm learning this language for work atm which I why I specify this language, I'm just not far enough ahead in it to fix the issue myself yet!

**EDIT** - also have some knowledge of python & js as other language options. Just really need to find a way to automate this process, as will soon have >120 files each week that will need the date format fixing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us how are you starting to doit and if you have any problem then we can help you.

Comment: Is there any other content in these files? Because if everything is like that, the solution would be pretty simple: change `/(\d{10})\s(\d{10})/` with `20\\1\s20\\1`.

Comment: I will edit the post to show more of the file content. they vary from approx 8500 lines to 16000 lines. @AlekseiMatiushkin

Comment: If the content may vary, add more symbols, including `CEND` to the regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your file data is in a file called `data.txt`

```
module DataFixer
  class << self
    def fix(filename)
      data = File.read(filename)
      fixed_data = data.gsub(/(\d{10})\s(\d{10})/, "20\\1\s20\\2")
      File.open(filename, 'w') {|f| f.write fixed_data}
    end
  end
end

DataFixer.fix('data.txt')
```

Now your data has been fixed.  The logic is using a regex pattern match and substitution on capture groups.